# Cloudwatch Filter Against OpenSearch Logs

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs, amazon-cloudwatch-events

I followed the instructions from documentation, but could not find it useful in my scenario.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/FilterAndPatternSyntax.html#extract-log-event-values

I am able to filter json values as well as columns data, but unable to filter for example **took_millis[19]** value from the log. I tried multiple filters like this [,,,,,,took_millis >= 100,...], [,,,,,,f7=*took*, milliseconds>=100,...] but no luck so far.

I want to filter slow log queries that are taking more than 100ms.

Example log data for elasticsearch slow queries is attached. Please have a look and share the filter pattern for cloudwatch events.

`[2021-11-22T01:25:17,133][WARN ][index.search.slowlog.query] [319eDpW] [locations][1] took[19.3ms], took_millis[19], types[data_en], stats[], search_type[QUERY_THEN_FETCH], total_shards[6], source[...]`

Comment: Anyone can please help?

Comment: I tried another filter [,,,,,,f7=*took*, milliseconds>=5,...], but this couldn't help. As, this filter would be used to extract values from space-delimited log events